# JxMaps not drawing arrows at polyline

Tags: jxmaps

using JxMaps (Java Swing) I draw a polyline.
This works fine.
Now I'd like to add arrwos to the lines. Anyone having an idea whats wrong with my code?

```
...
Symbol icon = new Symbol();
icon.setPath("google.maps.SymbolPath.FORWARD_CLOSED_ARROW");

IconSequence iconSequence = new IconSequence();
iconSequence.setIcon(icon);
iconSequence.setOffset("100%");

options.setIcons(new IconSequence[]{iconSequence});

// Applying ALL options to the polyline
polyline.setOptions(options);
```

No Arrows appear

If I look at the Google Maps API, it looks very similiar:

```
// var lineSymbol = {
//        path: google.maps.SymbolPath.FORWARD_CLOSED_ARROW
//
// new google.maps.Polyline({
//icons: [{
//   icon: lineSymbol,
//            offset: '100%'
//}],
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possibility to use built-in symbol paths was introduced in JxMaps version 1.2.2. You can  download it from official product page: www.teamdev.com/jxmaps

You can add this kind of image using following code:

```
Symbol icon = new Symbol();
icon.setPath(StandardSymbol.BACKWARD_CLOSED_ARROW);
```

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the hint with the new version and your code lines. Now it works fine!